# Nested For Loop Data Storing

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, nested

I am trying to build a nested loop that would return N=1, i=1, j=1 then N=1,i=1,j=2 ... up to N=5,i=12,j=5. I save it to data frame. Does anyone have a clue how to do it? I would also love to add a fourth loop, say k, that would be 1 to 5 and so that the loop would save N, i, j and k in dataframe, all combinations of them (1,1,1,1 up to 5,12,5,5). Thanks!

```
P <- data.frame(PValue = numeric(), NValue=numeric())
P2 <- list()  

for (N in 1:5){
  for (i in 1:12){
    for (j in 1:5) {
    P[i, 1] <- N
    P[i, 2] <- i
    P[i, 3] <- j
    }
  }
 P2[[N]] <- P
}
final <- do.call(rbind, P2)
```

Comment: Best to provide sample data, current and expected output. Please use `dput(head(df,n))` to provide sample data. Your question is currently more of an XY problem. I also think(naively) using for loops defeats the purpose of using `data.table`.

Comment: alright I changed it to a sample code problem. Thanks @NelsonGon

Comment: (1,1,1,1) up to (1,12,5,5) or up to (5,12,5,5) . ?

Comment: up to 5,12,5,5 , Ill fix it .. thanks @maydin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand why you are dealing with the `loop` for this problem but, the solution is below,

```
my_vector <- vector()

for (N in 1:5){
  for (i in 1:12){
    for (j in 1:5) {
           for (k in 1:5) {

           my_vector[1] <- N
           my_vector[2] <- i
           my_vector[3] <- j
           my_vector[4] <- k

           if(N==1 & i==1 & j==1 & k==1) {

            df <- my_vector

           }else{

            df <- rbind(df,my_vector)
           }

    }
   }  
  }
 }
 tail(df)  

          [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
my_vector    5   12    4    5
my_vector    5   12    5    1
my_vector    5   12    5    2
my_vector    5   12    5    3
my_vector    5   12    5    4
my_vector    5   12    5    5
```

You can assign `rownames` and `colnames` if you wish. However, there is a simple solution for this problem which is the `expand.grid` function.

```
my_df <- expand.grid(1:5,1:12,1:5,1:5)

tail(my_df)

     Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
1495    5   11    5    5
1496    1   12    5    5
1497    2   12    5    5
1498    3   12    5    5
1499    4   12    5    5
1500    5   12    5    5
```

Comment: Alright thanks! I will need to use the first one and alter it since I am saving AIC out of linear regression for every combination so I uploaded only simplified issue. I needed  the nested loop mechanism .. once more many thanks!

Comment: Your welcome. Note that, I used a vector for assigning, so the output is matrix.You can convert it to a dataframe  by using  `as.data.frame` or you can assign the values to an empty data frame instead of vector as well.